# Is there a way to append tags, instead of replace them, when deploying resources with BICEP?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am trying to add tags to a Bicep deployment so i can see who or what deployed a resource. I notice however that existing tags get replaced when i use the tags.

```
param lastDeployedBy string = 'deliverypl'

param deployementDateTime string = utcNow('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')

var resourceTags = {
  LastDeployedBy: lastDeployedBy
  LastDeployedDateUTC: deployementDateTime
}

resource resourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
  tags: resourceTags
}
```

Is there a way to append the tags from bicep, or should i create a script to do this?

- Created a test resourcegroup with the bicep code.
- Added some manual tags to the resourcegroup
- Ran the bicep deployment again.
  = Manual tags are removed.

I would like it to append the tags added from the bicep deployment.

Comment: if you go to the deployment blade, you can see who deployed and when. otherwise i feel it's probably easier to get existing tags before deploying then pass then as parameter of the bicep file. `az group list --query "[?name=='rg-name'].tags"`

Comment: Thanks, i will use a script to just add tags from a pipeline. Because we are deploying bicep true pipelines and i want to know what pipeline deployed the resource last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I've deployed a bicep template for adding below tags as shown:

[image]

To append/concat, Use [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#union) operator for `object` as well as `string` params.

***I've taken your script and modified as follows to append the new tags to the existed one's.***

***vi main.bicep:***

```bash
@description('Specifies the location for resources.')
param  location  string = 'East US'
targetScope = 'subscription'
param  lastDeployedBy  string = 'deliverypl'
param  deployementDateTime  string = utcNow('19-12-2022 17:05')
var  resourceTags = {
LastDeployedBy: lastDeployedBy
LastDeployedDateUTC: deployementDateTime
}
resource  resourceGroup  'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
name: 'new'
location: location
tags: union(resourceTags,{
value : 'Appended'
})
}
```

***Build & Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Added*** `value:Appended` ***tag to the existed tags within the scope/resourcegroup:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is usefull but still would remove tags that are on the azure resource, unless i specify them in the bicep file. I could write a script that adds the existing tags as a parameter but would like to avoid that. If possible